# Building a map/flowchart to better understand a database

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, reporting-services, flowchart

I am interested in creating a map of my database, so that I may understand it better. I am having difficulties understanding which tables relate to other tables, and I think a map, or flowchart would help me greatly. Has anyone done this? If so, how did you accomplish it?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It's a database at my company

Comment: Sorry, I was asking which DB engine are you using? Oracle, Microsft SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, etc.

Comment: No problem, Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: You can try **SQL Server Management Studio Express**. Look at answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [SQL Server Management Studio Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961). Just right click on `Database Diagrams` and create a new diagram. You can select existing tables that you desire.

You can follow an excellent guide step by step [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/).

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much. Just what I needed.

Comment: While I can see how this would be useful, I might have a different problem. My database is massive. There are literally hundreds of tables.

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to this problem. Take a look at this answer,  [How to generate a diagram of a very large database schema (SQL Server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503223/how-to-generate-a-diagram-of-a-very-large-database-schema-sql-server), might help you

Answer (score 2):

If you have Microsoft visio, that's a good software in creating a flowchart.

Comment: I have used Visio, but unfortunately, my company doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

I use Lucid Chart (www.lucidchart.com) occasionally because we don't have Visio either. They offer a free account, which works pretty well, apart from the limit on the number of items you can put in one document (I want to say it's a limit of 60 entities).